# mysql delete relation from join table then delete row if it no longer contains any more relations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a users, lists and users_to_lists tables.

When a user removes themself from a list I use the following:

```
"DELETE FROM users_to_lists WHERE user_id=? AND list_id=?"
```

What I want to do is to clean up by deleting the list as well only if there are no more users left after the last user has removed themself from the list and not sure how to do that.

So what I would like to do is:
1. delete relation for user to list
2. check if list has any user relations
3. if no user relations, delete list

Wondering what the best practice is in this scenario

Comment: I think a trigger would be the best practice.

Comment: ok thanks.  I'll research triggers

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check out the documentation of [Foreign Key Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

You can refine your query by using the `ON_DELETE CASCADE` property. Check the documentation. If you have any query you can ask me in the comment.

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` doesn't do this. He wants to delete the parent when all children are deleted. `CASCADE` deletes the children when the parent is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this along with your delete statement to clean all the unused lists.

```
DELETE FROM list WHERE id <> (SELECT list_id FROM users_to_lists)
```